# which one is called first, onsavedinstancestaes or onpause

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know that which function is called first among them. If anybody knows then please do let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html. check the topic under **Saving Activity state**. Check the note also If the system calls `onSaveInstanceState()`, it does so before `onStop()` and **possibly before onPause()**. and the following note which @blackbelt suggested below.

Comment: always after, also `Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that your `onSavedInstanceState()` will be called before your activity is destroyed. But if Android OS calls `onSavedInstanceState()` then it will be called before `onPause()`

For more details please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause().

Answer (score 1):

`onSaveInstanceState()` is called before your activity is paused. So any info that it needs after it is potentially destroyed and can be retrieved from the saved Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

`onSavedInstanceState()` called first before activity pause
and`onRestoreInstanceState()`,called before your activity resume or ...,
you can save and load data on them,but better using of these data in `onPause()` or `onResume()` , not inside of `onSavedInstanceState()`